# Export JSON fetch React Native

Tags: android, json, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am exporting JSON by fetch from the URL. I think I have a binding issue if take from local data file working I'm not completely sure on how I should proceed to bind my function.

Data.js

```
const Json = require('./one.js'); // not working or  const Json = require('./two.json'); // working 

export default Json;
```

one.js

```
function getvals(){
    return fetch('http://xxxxxx')
   .then((response) => response.json())
   .then((json) => {
     return json.products;
   })
   .catch((error) => {
     console.error(error);
   });
  }
  
  getvals().then(response => response);
```

two.json

```
 [{"id":"1","category":"kkk","title":"sss"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing in `one.js` exports anything. With CommonJS-style modules, you export something by assigning it to a property on `exports` (or by reassigning the `exports` variable entirely).

But note that since what you're getting is only available **asynchronously**, other modules may request `one.js`'s default export before the asynchronous process has completed. The usual solution to that is export the promise from `fetch`:

```
module.exports = fetch('http://xxxxxx')
    .then((response) => {
       if (!response.ok)  {
           throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
       }
       return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
        return data.products;
    });
```

Also note that you need to check for HTTP success (the footgun in the `fetch` API) and you don't want to hide errors; let the users of the module know if the fetch fails.

Code using that would need to use the promise, e.g.:

```
require("./one.js")
.then(data => {
    // ...use the products...
})
.catch(error => {
    // ...handle the fact the fetch failed and the data won't be coming...
});
```

---

I don't know the React Native ecosystem, but if you can to switch to JavaScript modules ("ESM" = **E**CMA**S**cript **M**odules) instead (and if you want to), **someday** you'd be able to use a new feature called [top-level `await`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await). The V8 engine has it (behind a flag), presumably JavaScriptCore will at some stage. That would let you suspend module evaluation until the `fetch` completed, and directly export the result:

```
// With top-level `await` in an ESM module
export default await fetch('http://xxxxxx')
    .then((response) => {
       if (!response.ok)  {
           throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
       }
       return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
        return data.products;
    });
```

Modules using it would be able to get the products directly:

```
import products from "./one.js";
```

If you're using Webpack (again, I don't know the React Native ecosystem), it has [experimental support for it](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/pull/9177), too.

Comment: sir Its working good but it shows in the alert but not exporting


const json= require("./one.js")
.then(data => {
  alert(data)
})
.catch(error => {
   
});

  

export default json;

Comment: @YabazThampi - The answer doesn't say that would work. Also, you're mixing two different module styles there (CJS and ESM). Again: You can't export something you only get asynchronously (unless you have top-level `await` support in your environment).